# Send Designed text from Richtextbox to Listview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, chat, richtextbox

I'm working on a Chat project in my class.

I have to use winform for the Server and the Client.

I can send the text from the richtextbox to the listview, but after changing the color or the font of the text (by using two different buttons for color and font), the text design has changed on the richtextbox but NOT on the listview.

Comment: You want to know how to change the forecolor of an item in the ListView ? use listView1.Items[0].ForeColor = Color.Green;

Comment: Show your code? changing `ListViewItem` forecolor is simple.

Comment: the Listview has one column, and each row is for the message that the server or the client sends. I want to anable each client to choose their own color and font so that on the Listview messages from different clients will be in different design.

Comment: How are you going to keep track of which message came from which client to presist the style set by that client ?

Comment: Two clients can use the same design because their nickname is shown before the text. Is there any way to do what i want?
I just need to understand how to send the design text from the richtextbox to the listview.
Thank's for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will send the text from a `richTextBox1` to `ListView1` with Font and Color.

```
private void btnColor_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ColorDialog color = new ColorDialog();
    if (color.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        richTextBox1.ForeColor = color.Color;
    }
}

private void btnFont_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FontDialog font = new FontDialog();
    if (font.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        richTextBox1.Font = font.Font;
    }
}

private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listView1.Items.Add(richTextBox1.Text);
    listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].ForeColor = richTextBox1.ForeColor;
    listView1.Items[listView1.Items.Count - 1].Font = richTextBox1.Font;
}
```

Comment: I have another question though, how can I send the designed text from this form(Client form) to the server form? (I can send the text but without the design).

Comment: @Elad You want to send from a RichTextBox in your client form to a richtextbox in your server form?. If so, use the same logic. Send it then select it and color it

Comment: I want to send from the clients RichTextBox to the servers ListView and the same thing from the servers RichTextBox to the clients ListView.

Comment: @Elad How do u call the server form?. Do you use networking or just call the form normally?

Comment: I use TCP/IP. the client conect to the servers port and by send the message by binary serialization, then the server send this message to all clients. if you need more details please tell me.